# Trying to extract audience data from Google Analytics API

Tags: java, api, google-analytics, reporting

quick question here : I am using Google Analytics reporting API v4 to perform some extractions from GA data, all working as desired except for one set of Audience data.

Basically I'm querying Audience data with the following dimensions and metrics(also as described here : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=audience) :

```
Metrics :
    ga:visits

Dimensions :
    ga:dateHourMinute
    ga:dataSource
    ga:userAgeBracket
    ga:userGender
    ga:interestInMarketCategory
```

If I send a request with this combination, data is returned normally. However, if I add one more dimension of interest such `ga:city` , the API doesn't throws any errors, **but also does not return any data**.

Weird thing is that for other combination of dimensions/metrics with `ga:city` simply works correctly.

Any ideas on why it is not returning data, perhaps, how to make this work would be greatly appreciated since I'm stuck with this for some days :-|

Thanks in advance everyone !

Comment: Can you share with us the request you built?

Answer (score 1):

According to docs [ga:visits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_visits) in API V4 is deprecated, use `ga:sessions` instead.

Try with this combination:

```
metrics:

ga:sessions

Dimensions

ga:dateHourMinute
ga:dataSource
ga:userAgeBracket
ga:userGender
ga:interestInMarketCategory
ga:city
```

Comment: Indeed, ga:visits is deprecated, nice that you point it out. I’ve changed to query the API with this set :

Metrics :
 ga:sessions

Dimensions :
 ga:dateHourMinute
 ga:dataSource
 ga:userAgeBracket
 ga:userGender
 ga:interestInMarketCategory
 ga:city

However, even though with change, no data is returned :-|. I’ve tried other combinations but  regardless of the order if you insert any of _ga:userAgeBracket_, _ga:userGender_ and/or _ga:interestInMarketCategory_ the API simply keeps narrowing the results, or even returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For privacy reasons, and maybe because they do not want yout to be able to extract data to another system, Google does not allow that you narrow down data too accurately.

They do not want you to be able to guess private data (interests, gender, age bracket...) from a specific user.